# Why the logical operators are not working as expected?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

I am in a beginner CS course and I am trying to write a program in C that asks for a two digit number and returns the written out form of that number.  I have written all of the code and it works when I try the numbers 10-19 but not any others.  Compiled using C89 standard if that matters

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

printf("\n Number to Word Conversion Program");
printf("\n\n This program takes a two-digit number and outputs the English word for the number");

int number = 0;
int numberH1 = 0;
int numberH2 = 0;

printf("\n\n Please enter a two-digit number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);

numberH1 = number / 10;
numberH2 = number % 10;

if (number == 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)
{
    switch (number)
    {
        case 10:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Ten.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 11:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Eleven.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 12:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Twelve.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 13:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Thirteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 14:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Fourteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 15:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Fifteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 16:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Sixteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 17:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Seventeen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 18:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Eighteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
        case 19:
        {
            printf("\n\n The number entered was Nineteen.\n\n");
        }           
        break;
    }
}
else
{

switch (numberH1)
{
    case 2:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Twenty");    
    }   
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Thirty");    
    }   
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Forty"); 
    }   
    break;
    case 5:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Fifty"); 
    }   
    break;
    case 6:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Sixty"); 
    }   
    break;
    case 7:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Seventy");   
    }   
    break;
    case 8:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Eighty");    
    }   
    break;
    case 9:
    {
        printf("\n\n The numer entered was Ninety");    
    }   
    break;
}



switch (numberH2)
{
    case 0:
    {
        printf(".\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 1:
    {
        printf("-one.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        printf("-two.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        printf("-three.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        printf("-four.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 5:
    {
        printf("-five.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 6:
    {
        printf("-six.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 7:
    {
        printf("-seven.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 8:
    {
        printf("-eight.\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 9:
    {
        printf("-nine.\n\n");
    }
    break;
}
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (number == 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)` --> `if (9  < number && number < 20)`

Comment: It's spaghetti code. Use an array of strings, please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
 if (number == 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)
```

is a wrong approach. You cannot chain the logical operator like that.

As of now, because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), your code is essentially

```
if ( (number == 10) || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)
```

which evaluates to either

- `if ( 1 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)`

or

- `if ( 0 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 ||18 || 19)`

both of which will yield a TRUE value.

You have to use it like

```
if ((number == 10) || (number ==  11)||(number ==  12).....
```

As I can see, you're already using the `switch` statement, so the `if` check can be removed altogether. You need to add a `default` case to handle *other* numbers. You can add nested `switch` to get the things done.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was correct, but the solution can be easier if you try to use the condition below:

```
if( (number > 9) || (number < 20))
    { ...
    }
```

note that, in this case, you can just use:

```
if(number < 20)
```

because you already asked for a "two-digit number"

Comment: asking user for something does not guarantee getting it, better check anyway